# Is difference of Sys.time() a reliable execution time estimate in R?

Tags: r, execution-time

For the code snippet

```
start <- Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(2)
end <- Sys.time()
print(paste('Time difference :', end-start))
```

No surprises in the output

> [1] "Time difference : 2.01378774642944"

But for the below code snippet :

```
start <- Sys.time()
x <- matrix(rnorm(7500000), nrow=500, ncol=15000)
x <- cor(x)
end <- Sys.time()
print(paste('Time difference :', end-start))
```

I get the output as :

> [1] "Time difference : 1.20198894341787"

However, the execution of this code snippet actually takes about 50 seconds on my laptop.

Why this difference ?
Is this not an ideal way to measure execution time ?

Comment: Maybe `difftime(start, end, units = 'secs')` so you are always working with the same unit?

Comment: Besides the obvious units issue: No, it's not very reliable. You should use one of the benchmarking packages. If you don't want to do that, at least use `system.time`.

Comment: @Roland - Why is `system.time` better than `diff of Sys.time` ?

Comment: Try it and you'll see. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output I tried

First example - the calculation output is `2.2...` and it's in second.

```
> start <- Sys.time()
> Sys.sleep(2)
> end <- Sys.time()
> print(paste('Time difference :', end-start))
[1] "Time difference : 2.20864367485046"
> difftime(end, start, units = "mins")
Time difference of 0.03681073 mins
```

Second example - the calculation output is `1.77...` and it is in minutes

```
> start <- Sys.time()
> x <- matrix(rnorm(7500000), nrow=500, ncol=15000)
> x <- cor(x)
> end <- Sys.time()
> print(paste('Time difference :', end-start))
[1] "Time difference : 1.77510009209315"
> difftime(end, start, units = "mins")
Time difference of 1.7751 mins
```

You can see that the Time difference you output is actually in minutes but it doesn't state that is minutes or seconds so that it confusing. I recommend you use the `difftime()` function instead.

Comment: From my 1st example, I incorrectly assumed that 'end-start' is always in seconds.
print(end-start) however shows the unit as well.
So 'paste' seems to be the reason the unit gets removed.
With 'paste' in 'print', 'difftime' like you suggested seems to be best.